# Having hard time adding key to nested dictionary, Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, nested

Im working on a nested dictionary and it was working fine until i had to make some adjustments to it. This is the code from my python code now:

```
from io import BytesIO
import urllib2 as net
from lxml import etree
import lxml.html


dict = {}

urlList = []

urlList.append("http://gbgfotboll.se/serier/?scr=table&ftid=57109")
urlList.append("http://gbgfotboll.se/serier/?scr=table&ftid=57108")

for url in urlList:

    request = net.Request(url)
    response = net.urlopen(request)
    data = response.read()


    dom = lxml.html.parse(BytesIO(data))
    #all table rows


    xpatheval = etree.XPathDocumentEvaluator(dom)
    rows = xpatheval('//div[@id="content-primary"]/table[1]/tbody/tr')

    divName = xpatheval('//*[@id="content-primary"]/h1//text()')[0]
    trash, divisionName = divName.rsplit("- ")

    dict[divisionName]= {}

    for id,row in enumerate(rows):
        columns = row.findall("td")

        teamName = columns[0].find("a").text, # Lag
        teamName
        playedGames = columns[1].text, # S
        wins = columns[2].text,
        draw = columns[3].text,
        lost = columns[4].text,
        dif = columns[6].text, # GM-IM
        points = columns[7].text, # P - last column

        dict[divisionName].update({id :{"teamName":teamName, "playedGames":playedGames, "wins":wins, "draw":draw, "lost":lost, "dif":dif, "points":points }})

print dict
```

I will only post three rows of the printed dictionary to explain what i need to do. This is what it prints out now:

```
{u'Div 3 Mellersta G\xf6taland, herrar': {
  0: {
  'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': ('Gunnilse IS',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)},
  1: {
'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': (u'G\xf6tene IF',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}, 
  2: {
'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': ('Hestrafors IF',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}},

u'Div 3 Nordv\xe4stra G\xf6taland, herrar': {
  0: {
'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': ('Ahlafors IF',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)},
   1: {
'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': (u'Dalen/ Kroksl\xe4tts FF',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)},
   2: {
'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': (u'IFK Fj\xe4r\xe5s',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)},



etc...
```

Anyway what i need to do is to add another key to the nested dicationary so it would look something like this:

```
{u'Div 3 Mellersta G\xf6taland, herrar': {
 0:{ <------- this is added, increases for every main key
  0: {
  'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': ('Gunnilse IS',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)},
  1: {
'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': (u'G\xf6tene IF',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}, 
  2: {
'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': ('Hestrafors IF',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}},

u'Div 3 Nordv\xe4stra G\xf6taland, herrar': {
 1:{ <------- this is added, increases for every main key
  0: {
'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': ('Ahlafors IF',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)},
   1: {
'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': (u'Dalen/ Kroksl\xe4tts FF',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)},
   2: {
'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': (u'IFK Fj\xe4r\xe5s',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)},
```

what i tried to do then was this, i marked what changed i did from the previous code:

```
i = 0  # <------- this is added
for url in urlList:

    request = net.Request(url)
    response = net.urlopen(request)
    data = response.read()


    dom = lxml.html.parse(BytesIO(data))
    #all table rows


    xpatheval = etree.XPathDocumentEvaluator(dom)
    rows = xpatheval('//div[@id="content-primary"]/table[1]/tbody/tr')

    divName = xpatheval('//*[@id="content-primary"]/h1//text()')[0]
    trash, divisionName = divName.rsplit("- ")

    dict[divisionName]= {}

    for id,row in enumerate(rows):
        columns = row.findall("td")

        teamName = columns[0].find("a").text, # Lag
        teamName
        playedGames = columns[1].text, # S
        wins = columns[2].text,
        draw = columns[3].text,
        lost = columns[4].text,
        dif = columns[6].text, # GM-IM
        points = columns[7].text, # P - last column

        dict[divisionName].update({i:{id :{"teamName":teamName, "playedGames":playedGames, "wins":wins, "draw":draw, "lost":lost, "dif":dif, "points":points }}})  
  # up here, this is added (i before id)
i = i+1  # <------- this is added
print dict
```

but it prints out like this:

```
{u'Div 3 Mellersta G\xf6taland, herrar': {
   0: {
     11: {'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': (u'V\xe5rg\xe5rda IK ',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}}},
u'Div 3 Nordv\xe4stra G\xf6taland, herrar': {
  0: 
   {11: {'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': (u'\xc4lvsborg FF',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}}}}
```

**EDIT1**

This is without me trying to add the third level: The original output:

```
Timocins-MacBook-Air:~ timo$ python test.py
{u'Div 3 Mellersta G\xf6taland, herrar': {0: {'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': ('Gunnilse IS',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}, 1: {'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': (u'G\xf6tene IF',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}, 2: {'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': ('Hestrafors IF',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}, 3: {'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': (u'Holmalunds IF Alings\xe5s',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}, 4: {'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': (u'IFK Falk\xf6ping FF',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}, 5: {'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': ('IFK Tidaholm',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}, 6: {'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': ('Lerums IS',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}, 7: {'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': (u'Lunden \xd6ver\xe5s BK',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}, 8: {'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': ('Skara FC',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}, 9: {'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': (u'S\xe4vedalens IF',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}, 10: {'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': ('Vara SK ',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}, 11: {'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': (u'V\xe5rg\xe5rda IK ',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}}, u'Div 3 Nordv\xe4stra G\xf6taland, herrar': {0: {'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': ('Ahlafors IF',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}, 1: {'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': (u'Dalen/ Kroksl\xe4tts FF',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}, 2: {'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': (u'IFK Fj\xe4r\xe5s',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}, 3: {'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': (u'IFK \xc5m\xe5l ',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}, 4: {'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': ('IK Virgo',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}, 5: {'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': ('Kungsbacka IF',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}, 6: {'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': ('Melleruds IF',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}, 7: {'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': ('Skoftebyns IF',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}, 8: {'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': ('Vallens IF',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}, 9: {'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': (u'V\xe4nersborgs IF',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}, 10: {'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': (u'V\xe4stra Fr\xf6lunda IF',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}, 11: {'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': (u'\xc4lvsborg FF',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}}}
```

This is with your code:

```
Timocins-MacBook-Air:~ timo$ python test.py
{u'Div 3 Mellersta G\xf6taland, herrar': {0: {11: {'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': (u'V\xe5rg\xe5rda IK ',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}}}, u'Div 3 Nordv\xe4stra G\xf6taland, herrar': {0: {11: {'draw': ('0',), 'lost': ('0',), 'playedGames': ('0',), 'dif': ('0',), 'teamName': (u'\xc4lvsborg FF',), 'points': ('0',), 'wins': ('0',)}}}}
```

**EDIT2** to make it even MORE clear what i need

```
key1{
  key2{ <-- THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ADD, ONE KEY2 PER KEY1
   key3{
    item,
    item,
    item,
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`i += 1` is outside the for loop, which means the value keeps being 0 (and therefore the field in the dictionary gets overwritten each time) until the entire for loop finishes.

Comment: Did not help at all, got the same result

Comment: Looking a bit more closely at what you want, I do not see the difference from what you're creating. The only thing that you add is some formatting (visuals), specifically a return for the second nesting level. Both of them have 3 levels of nesting. If you really want some formatting import the `json` module and do `json.dumps(dictionary, indent=2, sort_keys=True)`. That gives a sorted (dictionaries are unsorted by nature) view with all nested dictionaries on a new line an indented with 2 spaces.

Comment: watch closesly, the first one has 2 layers, second which i want has 3 layers.

Comment: See the added pictures to the post for clarity. There is no difference, just formatting/

Comment: Haha oh thats how u ment it. But as i said the original output should have like 10 rows per main key. The result as you see is one row per main key. Its like overwriting 11 times the same row and then i can only see the latest row that was overwritten get it? .

In my question i mentioned that will only post like 3 rows of the original dictionary that should be printed. Meaning after changing to three levels it should still have the same amount of rows.

Comment: oh, thanks! and now i see your error. `i +=1` is outside the for loop.

Comment: No thats not it.. You dont get my problem and what i want to acheive do you?  It is pretty clear what i want it to look like and putting i += 1 in the for loop does not solve the problem as i need, ONLY ONE second level per MAIN key

Comment: You are making key one (divisionname) in a loop. Value "i" is not incremented inside that loop. Only at the end of the entire snippet. You have to increment it inside the first loop.

Comment: Right now you are _never_ incrementing i. It will always stay 0.

Comment: It was not visible by this code my bad but i am incrementing it, and it is in the for loop it still wont solve the prob